# Blackberry BrowserField2 and AJAX

Tags: java, ajax, blackberry, browserfield

I'm trying to embed a browser in my Blackberry app.  It has some ajax functionality.

For testing purposes I have an asp.net page with a dropdownlist (with AutoPostBack=true) that updates a label with the selected list item's text when the index changes.  The text is updated on the screen without a page refresh via an UpdatePanel.  When I use the BrowserField control (net.rim.device.api.browser.field2.BrowserField) I can load the page fine, but when I select a new item from the dropdownlist the new text is never displayed.

Is there a way to do something like this with the BrowserField?

```
BrowserFieldConfig config = new BrowserFieldConfig();
config.setProperty(BrowserFieldConfig.JAVASCRIPT_TIMEOUT,new Integer(20));
config.setProperty(BrowserFieldConfig.JAVASCRIPT_ENABLED,Boolean.TRUE);
BrowserField bf = new BrowserField(config);
add( bf );
bf.requestContent( _url );
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following also.

```
bf.getRenderingOptions().setProperty(
                RenderingOptions.CORE_OPTIONS_GUID,
                RenderingOptions.JAVASCRIPT_ENABLED, Boolean.TRUE);
```

Where bf is the BrowserField Object.